# How to send a message when a new channel is created under a specific category discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to create a discord bot in javascript, which sends a message to freshly created channel under a specific category.
So everytime a new channel is created it should send the same message in that channel.

I hope someone can help me as I have no idea how I can archive that

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO :D I'm sorry but this is not a place where we write code for you. You should at least try something by yourself and if there are any bugs in your code you can post a question about that ^^ Just take a [tour] and learn [ask], before asking future questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the discord.js documentation for the [Discord Client class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client).

In the events section, you'll see the `channelCreate` event. To handle that event, do something like:

```
client.on("channelCreate", (channel) => {
    console.log(`Channel ${channel} created.`);
});
```

You can use `channel.send("message")` to send your message.